# Ember component not floating right

Tags: ember.js

I have some ember code:

```
{{#each this}}
    <div class="item">
      <div class="right floated tiny blue ui label">{{status}}</div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header"><a>{{id}} - {{name}}</a></div>
        <small>last updated {{pretty-date lastUpdated}}, currently assigned to {{title-case owner.name}}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
 {{/each}}
```

This works great. My status is floated to the right and the project id and name appear to the left.

I want to do some extra things with the status so I'm moving it into a component.

```
{{#each this}}
    <div class="item">
    {{labeled-stat status=status}}
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header"><a>{{id}} - {{name}}</a></div>
        <small>last updated {{pretty-date lastUpdated}}, currently assigned to {{title-case owner.name}}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
 {{/each}}
```

Then my component.hbs

```
<div class="right floated tiny blue ui label">{{status}}</div>
```

When this displays I'm getting an extra div around the status that says

```
<div class="ember408">
```

This is causing my item to not display correctly. Since ember is adding a new div, my status is actually on the left side.

Any way to fix this without changing the css?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I need to move the css out of the hbs component file and into the template:

```
{{labeled-stat status=status class="right floated tiny blue ui label"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the class names of the generated div using the [classNames](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_html-code-class-code-attribute) property. In that way you don't need to pass the `class` every time the compoment is used.

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/labeled-stat">
  {{status}}
</script>
```

Component:

```
App.LabeledStatComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: "right floated tiny blue ui label".w()
});
```

Usage:

```
{{labeled-stat status=status}}
```

I hope it helps